# Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies

Tags: entity-framework-6

I created an entity model based on SQL Server Table in my project. I write get operation on button click. When I am opening the page for first time its working fine for me. but on button click I am getting the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I tried putting

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

in app.config, but it doesn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

[I found this solution which worked for me.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/es-ES/f3d2a84b-2662-4126-9776-026deb4f1363/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-entityframework-version6000-cultureneutral?forum=windowsazurezhchs)

Basically go to Entity Framework in the references section, go to it's properties and select "Copy Local" = "True".

Credit to Respuestas/Jambor